# Findbugs not excluding methods in our java application

Tags: java, findbugs

I have added the following in the findbugs exclude.xml file

```
<Match>
    <Class name="com.ebay.kernel.service.invocation.SvcInvocationConfig" />
    <Method name="getConnectionConfig" />
    <Bug pattern="IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC" />
</Match>
```

The code that needs to be ignored

```
public ConnectionConfig getConnectionConfig() {
    return m_connectionConfig;
}
```

because Findbugs reports that

```
m_connectionConfig suffers from (inconsistent synchronization) BUG - IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC
```

But for some reason my findbugs are not getting ignored.

and when I do following -

```
<Match>
    <Class name="com.ebay.kernel.service.invocation.SvcInvocationConfig" />
    <Bug pattern="IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC" />
</Match>
```

The findbugs is getting ignored for the entire class but as soon as I introduce

```
<Method name="getConnectionConfig">
```

tag in between, findbugs stops getting ignored for that method.

Can someone help me figure out why?

Comment: What are you using to run FindBugs (maven target, gradle, etc.)? Do you know if your `findbugsExclude.xml` file is being used when it is ran? Might need to include your build logic.

Comment: My gut tells me you should try including a Match element for the field as well.  My brain tells me you should try being more coarse (matching only the Bug for example) to eliminate typos/scoping issues.  You may want to consider ignoring the bug entirely anyway since it can give you [false positives](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC).

Comment: My findbugsExclude.xml file works fine, I am able to exclude classes, packages, and also fields, but I am not able to exclude methods.

Comment: I am using http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html as a reference. Let me know if you guys are aware of other links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC` warning is issued on a data member (field), according to its usages by various methods, constructors, static blocks, etc. and not on the method itself, so you can't ignore it with a `<Method>` element.

Instead, you could use a `<Field>` element:

```
<Match>
    <Class name="com.ebay.kernel.service.invocation.SvcInvocationConfig" />
    <Field name="m_connectionConfig" />
    <Bug pattern="IS2_INCONSISTENT_SYNC" />
</Match>
```

Comment: It works at field level, But I really wanted to ignore the findbugs for this field  (m_connectionConfig) only in this method ( getConnectionConfig() ) and not everywhere ? Let me know if there's a way to achieve that ?

Comment: @user1675173 I'm not aware of a way to exclude this warning only for a single method, sorry.